# MVVMCROSS - Pass a parameter to a ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to pass a parameter to a child ViewModel constructor which throws "MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel ... MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to resolve parameter for parameter myParam of type MyType..."

**MyChildViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyChildViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private MyType _myParam;
    public MyType MyParam
    {
        get { return _myParam; }
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _myParam, value))
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyParam);
            }
        }
    }

    public MyChildViewModel(MyType myParam)
    {
        _myParam = myParam;
    }

}
```

In my parent ViewModel I have:

```
public ICommand ShowDialogCommand { get; private set; }
ShowDialogCommand = new MvxCommand<MyType>(e => ShowViewModel<MyChildViewModel>(e));
```

Parent activity call:

```
ViewModel.ShowDialogCommand.Execute(VarOfMyType);
```

I am obviously doing something wrong. Is this even remotely acceptable approach to pass data to a child ViewModel? What's the best practice?

Thank you in advance for your valuable time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read up on the documentation 
it is easy to pass object with the MvxNavigationService: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation

Note that the documentation is for MvvmCross 5.2 which is currently in a nightly release, but almost the same works for 5.0 and onwards.

In your ViewModel this could look like:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
    public MyViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public override void Prepare()
    {
        //Do anything before navigating to the view
    }

    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        await _navigationService.Navigate<NextViewModel, MyObject>(new MyObject());
    }
}

public class NextViewModel : MvxViewModel<MyObject>
{
    public override void Prepare(MyObject parameter)
    {
        //Do anything before navigating to the view
        //Save the parameter to a property if you want to use it later
    }

    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        //Do heavy work and data loading here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Martijn00 for the prompt response. You are the best, I love mvvmcross! I am indeed on v5.0.5. Will your IMvxNavigationService example work in 5.0 as-is? What are the differences between 5.0 and 5.2 that I should be aware of?

Comment: The difference is the override for `void Prepare(MyObject parameter)`. In 5.0 this is `Task Initialize(MyObject parameter)`, but we changed that.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much! Child NextViewModel v5.0: `public override Task Initialize(MyObject parameter)` and `return Task.FromResult(false);` Parent ViewModel - use `MvxAsyncCommand`: `SomeMethodCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(SomeMethod);`

Answer (score 2):

From [this website](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3684/mvvmcross-passing-parameter) the way they did it is (adapted and modified for your case):

```
public ICommand ShowDialogCommand { get; private set; }
ShowDialogCommand = new MvxCommand<MyType>(ShowMyVM);

private void ShowMyVM(MyType e)
{
    if (e != null)
        ShowViewModel<SingleClientViewModel>(e);
    else
    {
        //handle case where your parameter is null
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it. It does not solve the underlying issue but +1 for the null check and your time.